# Transform Query from SQL to Eloquent on Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I made a SQL query on my phpMyAdmin, to select the Top Products of an e-shop.

```
SELECT 
   sum(total_price), product_code, product_title, count(quantity) 
FROM 
   baskets, orders 
WHERE 
   baskets.order_id = orders.id 
   AND orders.cmd_valide = 1 
GROUP BY 
   product_code 
ORDER BY 
   sum(total_price) 
DESC LIMIT 3;
```

I have Baskets and Orders model, but I can't write the Eloquent version.

For now, i wrote:

```
$basket = Basket::join('orders', 'baskets.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
                    ->select('product_code')
                    ->get();
```

When i tried to add a groupby or a conditionnal query on the joined table, i have errors :(

What i'm doing wrong ?
Thanks!
Vincent

Comment: "_i have errors_" Please **always** post the complete error message(s) you get in your question

Comment: Convert your comma-style joining to INNER JOIN.

Comment: *What i'm doing wrong ?* Your query is incorrect (incomplete grouping). Either remove `product_title` from the output or aggregate it (for example, use ANY_VALUE() function).

Comment: you provide very little information on your question, when your question is about query, at least provide us the schema, what do the `basket` table contain? what about the `orders`? What are their relationship?